# Design rationality of expression levels in the Java grammar

Tags: java, parsing, grammar

I'm currently looking at the Java 7 grammar, and trying to figure out why several different expression levels are used. Clearly, there are some design decision made to avoid certain constructs that are not valid. However, in the documentation of the Java grammar I am not able to find these decisions.

For instance, consider the production `"Expression1Rest: ? Expression : Expression1"`. Why is the "if-part" an Expression, and the else-part an Expression1?

This means that the following Java code does not result in a syntax error in NetBeans:

```
String value = "";
String x = value.isEmpty() ? x = "empty" : "no";
```

The official Java grammar can be found here:
[reference link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html)

The relevant expression productions:

```
Expression: 
    Expression1 [AssignmentOperator Expression1]

Expression1: 
    Expression2 [Expression1Rest]

Expression1Rest: 
    ? Expression : Expression1

Expression2:
    Expression3 [Expression2Rest]

Expression2Rest:
    { InfixOp Expression3 }
    instanceof Type

Expression3: 
    PrefixOp Expression3
    ( (Expression | Type) ) Expression3
    Primary { Selector } { PostfixOp }
```

Is there some documentation / research paper that explains the decisions behind the Java grammar?

Answer (score 1):

The grammar that you have posted allows the left-hand-side of an assignment operator to be a conditional expression:

```
shouldSetFoo() ? foo : bar = 47;
```

So it would naturally cause ambiguities if the "else" branch of a conditional expression could itself be an assignment expression.

This problem does not affect the "then" branch, since the `?` and `:` set off that branch explicitly, preventing any ambiguity.

Comment: (BTW, I totally didn't realize until now that Java allowed the left-hand-side of an assignment operator to be a conditional expression. You learn something new every day!)

Comment: It doesn’t. The grammar might allow such a piece of code to be *parsed* but it still won’t get *compiled* as the conditional expression produces a value and Java does not allow assigning a value to a value. The grammar will also allow `foo() = 1;` but that’s the same story.

Comment: @Holger: You're right. [§15.26 "Assignment Operators"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) requires that the left-hand-side be a "variable", and although nothing seems to *explicitly* state that the result of a conditional expression is always a "value" rather than a "variable", that seems to be the only sensible reading (since "The chosen operand expression is then evaluated and the resulting **value** is converted to the type of the conditional expression as determined by the rules stated above").

Comment: To me it looks like the grammar in chaptare 15 and 18 differs at this point. I asked about a another (apparent) difference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861727/is-the-grammars-in-java7-spec-really-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is probably to reduce the grammar for expressions and handle all binary operators in one rule (instead of one for each predecedence level). This could simplify things if you're only interrested in validating the syntax, but probably not so useful if you're going to actually interpret the expression (in which case the grammar in chapter 15 is more useful).

Whether the syntax in chapter 15 and 18 is equivalent is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861727/is-the-grammars-in-java7-spec-really-equivalent).